# unexpected Perl CGI.pm error when posting from multipart/form-data

Tags: forms, apache, perl

I've solved this problem twice before with a quick fix.  Now I can't remember what that quick fix is, and I'd like to fix it right anyway.

When I post from a form of `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, and then create a new CGI object in the target script, i.e.:

```
my $query = new CGI;
```

I get the following error in my apache error log:

```
Malformed multipart POST: data truncated, referer: http...
```

I've confirmed this is where the error is occurring by placing die statements before and after the above mentioned statement.  And this the exact problem I've had before.

I'm running on Windows XP, Perl 5.8.8.  I've gone through various linux servers over the years and have never had this problem on one of them.

The fix to the problem before was to downgrade to a slightly older version of CGI.pm.  Today I thought I'd try upgrading to the most recent version, since it's been some time since I've tried a newer version.  But CGI.pm 4.20 still yields the same exact error.

It doesn't matter if there's any data on the form.  When it posts the error is generated.  And without the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` the error doesn't occur.

I'm reluctant to upgrade to a newer version of Perl because I have things just exactly where I want them and hate to risk messing that up.

Any ideas or thoughts?

**Edit:** It doesn't matter what browser I use, and also I can't remember what version of CGI.pm I downgraded to, which is why I said I can't remember the quickfix.

**Edit2:** Here's the exact code for my form:

```
<form action="/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data"> <input type="hidden" name="action"
value="update"> <input type="file" name="test"> <input type="submit"
value="submit"> </form>
```

And now that it's not causing internal server errors, I'm unable to create a valid filehandle to the file I try to upload on the form.  So the problem isn't solved afterall. I guess that was just my wishful thinking.

Comment: Please add the lines `use Data::Dumper; warn Dumper [<STDIN>];` *before* the `CGI->new` and post the output that you get. It would also be nice to see your HTML form

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this when I posted below.  I followed your instructions and now it all works.  Thanks!

Comment: If removing that line fixed the problem then it sounds like STDIN is empty. Please can you show your HTML if you're at all interested in fixing this properly?

Comment: <form action="/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type=hidden name=action value=update>
         <input type=submit value="submit">
         </form>

Comment: I did notice that after I added the file input back to the form there was an error.  The error log shows: $VAR1 = [], although this doesn't generate an internal server error.  I'm not familiar with data::dumper and how it works, or I would have mentioned this sooner.

Comment: Maybe this will be more useful to you:

Comment: Hmm nothing wrong there that I can see. Would you add the `Dumper` code above and tell me what output you get when you have a moment?

Comment: By the way, that code will stop the program from working and should be added only to see what data the form is sending and then removed again. Sorry that I didn't make that clear

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a more extensive reading of the error log after I added a file input to the form:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryVLrUuePcs8gqhOtJ\r, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ',, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"\r, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ',, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] '\r, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ',, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] 'update\r, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ',, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] '------WebKitFormBoundaryVLrUuePcs8gqhOtJ\r, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ',, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"; filename=""\r, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ',, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ',, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] '\r, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ',, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] '\r, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ',, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] '------WebKitFormBoundaryVLrUuePcs8gqhOtJ--\r, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ', referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:49 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ];, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
[Tue Jun 16 17:56:50 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] $VAR1 = [];, referer: http://gbc4.loc/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi
```

Comment: Update:  now it's working just fine.  I have no idea why.  Here's the exact form: <form action="/prgs/gbc4_members_account.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update">
         <input type="file" name="test">
         <input type="submit" value="submit">
         </form>  Again, no errors.

Comment: please update your original question and put the html form there;  also please use  this version for dumper diagnostics `Data::Dumper->new([join '', <STDIN>])->Useqq(1)->Dump`

Comment: The data::dumper statement you told me to use doesn't work.  Can't locate object method "new" via package "Data::Dumper"

Comment: If you remove `use Data::Dumper;` then that might happen